# Data collector- receive external data

Tags: laravel-5.1

I want to build an application to show data from my database, simple enough, but can I also use Laravel to listen for data sent from external devices (PLC, barcode reader, scanner etc.) and store these data in the database. Incomming data could be one single value or csv string. Fx. temperature sent to port 5050. (No http POST or GET request, just simple value on TCP)

Comment: A lot of packages are written for 'Laravel ' so you can install them and use it. One of them could be: https://github.com/dineshrabara/barcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** the answer depends very much on the external devices in question and the architecture of your application.

The architecture of your application and your hardware is going to determine the answer to this question. Specifically, are these external devices connected to the server or to a client? Are they USB human interface devices (as many barcode scanners are) or something else?

Remember, Laravel is a web application framework. It is designed to facilitate the development of web applications: ie. applications that work primarily in a server-client model, where the client makes requests to the server and the server responds. As such, it's not really well suited to the continuous polling of external devices that you seem to be describing. It excels at the other part, though, displaying the data via a web application.

If the external devices are attached to the server, then your best bet is a separate application (distinct from your Laravel application) which samples the external data and inserts it into your database. You *could* probably do it with a Laravel cron job, but it's likely you're going to be relying on code much closer to the hardware, so a simple bash script or similar low level application might be easier.

If the external devices are attached to the client, you have the same issues as above, plus the problem of transporting the data to the server. Again, you could probably put something together using Laravel jobs and the like, but it's not really well suited to that.

The one exception to this discussion that you mentioned is the barcode scanner. Many barcode scanners which connect to a PC via USB appear to the PC as a keyboard and the results of the scanning are sent to the PC as a set of keypresses. If you're using a barcode scanner like this, you could create a web page where the user scans data into an `<input>` element and the form gets submitted. This would be much closer to the kind of job that Laravel is designed for.

Comment: Kryten you are right. I think in my eager to use Laravel I forgot the webserver in the middle. So in that sense it has to be through some HTTP  communication.
I gues a Phyton job is the right solution.